# Xcode Build and Archive won't save ipa file

Tags: xcode

I have used Xcode's Build and Archive feature to create adhoc build many times.  Usually when you click Share after Build and Archive, you will be presented a dialog box asking you where to save the ipa file.  However, with one of our recent projects, we have not been able to get that dialog after clicking Share.  Reinstalling xcode doesn't fix it.
This is in reference to Xcode 3.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution and posted it [here](http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2011/4/17/xcode-build-and-archive-sharing-problem-and-solution.html)